# Conserto ou Concerto?

Tags: ortografia, significado

É visto constantemente nas redes sociais o uso equivocado das palavras "Conserto" e "Concerto".

Qual a diferença entre essas palavras?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answerable by a simple dictionary look-up (or Google Translate) and indicates no prior research effort.

Answer (score 6):

*Conserto* é uma forma verbal do verbo consertar, ou um nome (significando *arranjo*, neste caso). *Concerto* é um nome, que descreve uma atuação musical.